# Basic Meteor Asynchronous Concept: Submit an Email and Send Email

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am really new to Meteor framework, and having some hard time grasping its concept, coming from a traditional response and request background (in NodeJS asynchronous callback style) to Meteor.

I am just trying to build a landing page, which tells me about your name and email address.  After the user clicks submit, I want the user to be saved in the database (MongoDB), and sends a request to Mandrill endpoint, so that Mandrill can send an email to that specific email address.

My approach in traditional response and request will be like this.  The user submit their name and email address, and it will be a POST request to my server, and on my server, my ORM will save it to the database, and upon callback success, I hit a request to Mandrill to send an email to this specific user.

My code in Meteor now as follows:

```
Template.welcome.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var subscribe = {
      name: $(e.target).find('[name="name"]').val(),
      email: $(e.target).find('[name="email"]').val()
    };

    var errors = validateSubscribes(subscribe);
    if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0) {
      for (var type in errors) {
        toast(errors[type], 2000);
      }
      return;
    }

    Subscribes.insert(subscribe, function(error, result) {
      if (error)
        return toast("Oops, something is wrong, try again");

      if (result) {
        $(e.target).find('button:submit')
                   .attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(e.target).find('[name="name"]')
                   .val("")
                   .attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(e.target).find('[name="email"]')
                   .val("")
                   .attr("disabled", "disabled");

        return toast('Thank you for subscribing!', 3000);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And my Mandrill code is as follows (got it from https://atmospherejs.com/wylio/mandrill)

```
#server code
Meteor.Mandrill.sendTemplate({
    "key": "YOUR_MANDRILL_API_KEY", // optional, if you set it in with Meteor.Mandril.config() already
    "template_name": "YOUR_TEMPLATE_SLUG_NAME",
    "template_content": [
      {}
    ],
    "message": {
        "global_merge_vars": [
            {
                "name": "var1",
                "content": "Global Value 1"
            }
        ],
        "merge_vars": [
            {
                "rcpt": "email@example.com",
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "name": "fname",
                        "content": "John"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "lname",
                        "content": "Smith"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "to": [
        {"email": email@example.com}
        ]
    }
});
```

Also, on the collection, I do an allow of Subscribe

```
Subscribes = new Mongo.Collection('subscribes');

Subscribes.allow({
  insert: function(userId, subscribe) { return true; }
});

validateSubscribes = function(subscribe) {
  var errors = {},
      regExp = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

   if (!subscribe.name)
    errors.name = 'Please fill in a name';

  if (!subscribe.email || !regExp.test(subscribe.email))
    errors.email = 'Please fill in a valid email';

  return errors;
};
```

I have three questions:

- Why use allow? Why don't use Meteor.method and Meteor.call?
- Where do I put mandrill code? Inside the callback? I thought Meteor style of programming should be synchronous style?
- I can put all of my validation logic here, and all of my jQuery UI logic here in this submit form event click alone.  I can see this gets bloated quickly.  Is there any specific way of organizing all of these?

Thank you so much for the answer.  Meteor is super cool, just need to wrap my head around it a little bit.

Christian

Answer (score 1):

1. Many of us exclusively use `Meteor.Method`. See the Discover Meteor blog for a good starting place. https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-methods-client-side-operations/ 
   In my case, almost every document I insert has a datestamp & userId attached, so I have to use methods, otherwise users could declare an arbitrary Id on the client. Even if it wasn't necessary, it's just a simpler way of thinking instead of running through allow/deny logic in your head (remember, 1 TRUE and you're screwed). This is why some folks recommend only using deny, or installing another package...
2. Meteor on the server uses fibers, which makes the code LOOK synchronous. https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/nodejs-using-futures
   I'd organize this by moving your `insert` to a `Meteor.method`. Then, I'd call mandrill with the document you gathered from the client & verified on the server. (IIRC Mandrill requires an APIkey, so you probably don't want that hanging out in client code, anyways)
3. Look into collection2 and simple schema. It obviates a lot of the messy server-side checks, picks, and cleaning. The learning curve is a little high & there are other solid packages, but this is unofficially the meteor defacto standard.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your reply.  Can you give me a code example for No. 2?

Comment: What specifically would you like? That package's github page has a good example with the `this.sendEmail()` function. From the client, I'd call `Meteor.call("sendMyMail",options)` And on the server, `sendMyMail` would be a function that takes in options, validates, and returns a call to `Meteor.Mandrill.send()`, or you could call .send() directly if you didn't have any validation. Without a callback, `Meteor.call` runs synchronously, but won't issue a return value to the client.